# What is the maximum value of $ f(x)=\frac{2 \sin (3 x)}{3 \sin (x)+3 \sqrt{3} \cos (x)} (\frac{\pi}{3}<x<\frac{2\pi}{3})$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: What is the maximum value of $$ f(x)=\frac{2 \sin (3 x)}{3 \sin (x)+3 \sqrt{3} \cos (x)} (\frac{\pi}{3}<x<\frac{2\pi}{3})$$
I have done my work here 
$$f'(x)=\frac{2 \left(2 \sqrt{3} \cos (2 x)+\sqrt{3} \cos (4 x)-8 \sin ^3(x) \cos (x)\right)}{3 \left(\sin (x)+\sqrt{3} \cos (x)\right)^2}=0$$
I tried to solve problems but I couldn't make further progress

Comment: Simplify denominator to express it as a pure sine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Notice, $$\frac{2\sin(3x)}{3\sin(x)+3\sqrt{3}\cos (x)}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos (x)}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+\cos (x)\sin \frac{\pi}{3}}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$$
Now, $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)3\cos(3x)-\sin (3x)\cos \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\sin^2 \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=0$$
$$2\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos(3x)+\left(\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos(3x)-\sin (3x)\cos \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)=0$$
$$\sin \left(4x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-2\sin\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=0$$

Comment: Though you have simplified it, it does not answer the question

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)} $$
is a negative function on the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$, while $f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=0$.